# mysqli does not execute SQL, no error message

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am attempting to code a VERY simple "Hello World!" program using PHP and MySQL.

Things work until I add the line, "$rs = $db->query($sql);" and then I just get a blank screen.

What am I doing wrong??
Thank you!

### Code below:

```
<?
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$database = 'grc';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;

$link = mysqli_init();
$db = mysqli_real_connect($link, $host, $user, $password, $database, $port);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

printf('asdf\n\n');

$sql = 'SELECT productname FROM product WHERE productid=1';

$rs = $db->query($sql);
if (!$rs) {
    printf("%s\n", $db->error);
    exit();
}
printf('1sdfasdf');
?>
<html>
    <head>Hello world!</head>
    <body>Hello WORLD!!</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `<?php` in place of `<?` and make sure you have PHP error reporting turned on.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of your file to see if there's gonna be any errors on the page.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if your mysqli connection syntax is correct: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php

Comment: Turn on error logging dude

Comment: Turn on error logging. `ini_set("display_errors", true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

First, turned on errors by editing the php.ini.

Second, the error that showed up was this: 
"Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a boolean"

This was caused because this line:

```
$db = mysqli_real_connect($link, $host, $user, $password, $database, $port);
```

turned $db into a true/false.

Third, I replaced the code with this:

```
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$database = 'grc';
$host = 'localhost';

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}       

$sql = 'SELECT productname FROM grc.product WHERE productid=1';

$rs = $conn->query($sql);
if ($rs->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row=$rs->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "productname: " . $row["productname"] . "<br />";
        }
} else {        
        echo "Zero results.";
} 
$conn->close();
```

And it worked.

Did not use the mysqli_real_connect() or some of the other newest methods, but it works, I am using object-oriented mysqli and that is good enough for me.

Thanks all for the responses.